# How to load my app from client's domain name

Tags: cross-domain, subdomain, saas

I am building a SAAS product which is hosted on `abc.com` and i will have few clients with domains `client1.com`, `client2.org`, `client3.in` etc.

Now i want to serve my application to each client on their domains like `client1.com/app`, `client2.com/app`, `client3/com/app`

I dont want to host my code on their server..There will only be 1 base code & 1 DB which will be on my site `abc.com`. So my entire app should run on their domain

The question is, how do I configure this ? I mean `client.com` will point to their server but `client.com/app` will execute my application from my server with base url of their own domain ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

So i acheived this  by using `mod_proxy` in virtual host config file of client's server by adding the following line

```
ProxyRequests off 
ProxyPreserveHost off
ProxyPass /app http://mydomian.com 
ProxyPassReverse /app http://mydomian.com  
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://mydomian.com  http://client.com/app
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
```

It should be noted that `proxy`, `proxy_http` & `proxy_html` modules must be enabled which can be done by following commands

```
  sudo a2enmod proxy
  sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

`proxy_html` might not generally be available so it can be downloaded using this command

```
  sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

Link - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html